# when the value of ng-show is true then also element is not visible

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to hide and show tabs using ng-show . 
I have written the following code

```
 <li ng-show={{hidetabs}}  > <a data-toggle="tab" id="second_tab" href="#menu1">Customer Contacts</a></li>
            <li ng-show={{hidetabs}}> <a data-toggle="tab" id="third_tab" href="#menu2">CWC User Access</a></li>
      </ul>
```

and the code for controller is 
function($scope, ngDialog, $routeParams, $window , $location ) {

```
                $scope.aircraftlist = [];

                $scope.hidetabs=false;



                $scope.aircraft = {};
                $scope.nextfirsttab = function() {
                    $scope.hidetabs=true;
                    $("#second_tab").click();
                }
```

The problem is even when i am setting the value of hidetabs to true class is ng-hide . and if in the div put ng-show="hidetabs" it doesnt work at all .

Comment: You do not need the curly braces `{{}}` just do `ng-show="hidetabs"`. This may help [explain](http://jaketrent.com/post/when-to-use-curlies-in-angular-directives/) when the braces are needed.

Answer (score 1):

use ng-show variable inside quotation marks, also the interpolation is unnecessary

```
 <li ng-show="hidetabs"  > <a data-toggle="tab" id="second_tab" href="#menu1">Customer Contacts</a></li>
        <li ng-show="hidetabs"> <a data-toggle="tab" id="third_tab" href="#menu2">CWC User Access</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `{{}}` from `hidetabs`.

use `ng-show=hidetabs` instead of `ng-show={{hidetabs}}`.

```
<ul>
<li ng-show="hidetabs"> 
<a data-toggle="tab" id="second_tab" href="#menu1">Customer Contacts</a></li>
<li ng-show="hidetabs">
<a data-toggle="tab" id="third_tab" href="#menu2">CWC User Access</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Plnkr Demo :** http://plnkr.co/edit/q4eoglQUcxwNKvbjgQOF?p=preview